# Have two time capsules and use the one only as HDD and the other as router

Tags: time-capsule

I have two Time Capsules and I want to use both simultaneously. One as a router and the other as a HDD **only**.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the AirPort Utility and pick the AirPort accordingly:

**HDD:**

- Select the Wireless tab
- Network Mode: Off
- Select the Disks tab
- Tick: Enable file sharing

**Router:**

- Select the Wireless tab
- Network Mode: Create/Extend a wireless network
- Select the Disks tab
- Untick: Enable file sharing